# NodeJS porque tantos arquivos

Tags: javascript, node.js

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou iniciando a pouco tempo com NodeJS um projetinho em VUEJS, e vi que quando eu dou o comando

```
NPM INSTALL
```

ele cria cerca de 20.000 arquivos, minha aplicação chega a ficar com 100mb sem ter quase nenhuma dependência...

Para que serve tanta pasta e arquivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os pacotes que instalas com o `npm install` são programas necessários às dependências que referiste no `packacge.json`. Eles estão lá porque são precisos em alguma parte de programas/pacotes que irás usar.

Por exemplo, [o `webpack` sozinho tem 22 dependências](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json#L6-L28), e é uma peça essencial para compilar o código para se poder usar.

Podes sempre remover pacotes que já não precises, mas há partida, para teres as funcionalidades que precisas e para o código poder ser empacotado e ir (o mais leve possivel) para o cliente/utilizador, então são precisas essas dependências.

Esses programas vão para a pasta `node_modules` que deves ignorar com uma linha no `.gitignore` pois não deves "commitar" essas pastas ou copia-las. Se tiveres em conta que cada pacote tem as suas dependências, que têm as suas dependências... fica um circulo meio vicioso. Daí 100mb nesse caso.

Tenta manter só os pacotes que precisas, mas claro, há na `npm` muita coisa util e interessante... é mais fácil acumular que limpar.

Comment: Entendi, essas dependencias são como por exemplo: Um Visual Studio usa suas próprias dependencias para compilar projetos, só que no caso do NodeJS, nós conseguimos ver na pasta todos seus arquivos de dependencia, seria mais ou menos isso? Obrigado!

Comment: @Jackson exato. Lembra-te de ignorar a pasta e subpastas no `.gitignore`, para evitar ter lastro no Github por exemplo.

Comment: O que seria o Gitignore? não encontrei essa pasta. Obrigado!

Comment: @Jackson o `.gitignore`  é um ficheiro, com esse nome (sem extensão) que coloquei. Ele serve para dizer ao Github quais os ficheiros a ignorar para evitar fazer check-in e enviar para o Github ficheiros a mais. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore

Comment: Hmm entendi! Ficou claro. Obrigado! :)